# how to search goosh.org from the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh, command-line-interface

I'd like to write a simple bash script to search goosh.org from the command line and open the results in a browser. (Or maybe you wouldn't even call this a bash script at all since all it does is make a browser call.)

I created a file called goosh that contains one line:

```
open "http://goosh.org/#$1"
```

This works, without the need to enclose the search in quotation marks, when the search term is just one word:

```
$ goosh monarch
```

But it fails when I use multiple search terms:

```
$ goosh monarch butterfly
```

This doesn't work:

```
open "http://goosh.org/#$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces, hex value `0x20`, are converted to `%20` in a browser. You probably want to use `sed` on the input values:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | sed -e 's/ /%20/'
```

Will give you an output of

```
1%202%203%204%205%206%207%208
```

I'd suggest that you parse your script's `"$@"` inputs (everything provided to the script) in the same manner and see if that doesn't give you the results you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

Here's a simple function you can try:

```
function goosh() {
  ARGS=$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's/ /%20/g');
  echo "http://www.goosh.org/#$ARGS";
}
```

This won't actually call the site; it will just dump the output to your console (so you can make sure the variables are correct). Simply replace `echo` with `open` and it should be fine.

Example:

```
  $ goosh When will Apple buy stock in Microsoft
  http://www.goosh.org/#When%20will%20Apple%20buy%20stock%20in%20Microsoft
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I take those inputs, parse them, and open them in the browser?

Comment: Are you looking for a shell script specifically, or will a function work just as well (see edit to my post)?